# Getting stdObject array values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

Ok I'm working with the following code:

```
$userGuid = "2d7c4ca4-d1b6-4c2a-9106-33df1251d946";
$apiKey = "wuZBiCx2jWwbNJgw88M6jJvxp0LYBBG9o/cxgHZx+cdNVKaPnMASmbdbj/4oVrch5NZZlPULad0pamUar9kUrA==";

function query($connectorGuid, $input, $userGuid, $apiKey, $additionalInput) {

  $url = "https://api.import.io/store/connector/" . $connectorGuid . "/_query?_user=" . urlencode($userGuid) . "&_apikey=" . urlencode($apiKey);

  $data = array("input" => $input);
  if ($additionalInput) {
    $data["additionalInput"] = $additionalInput;
  }

  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  json_encode($data));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  return json_decode($result, true);

}

// Query for tile Teams and Links
$result = query("3997cc2e-4fce-4431-89da-0dc542d83b84", array(
  "webpage/url" => "http://msn.foxsports.com/foxsoccer/bundesliga/teams",
), $userGuid, $apiKey, false);

var_dump($result);
```

That returns the following:

```
array(6) {
    ["offset"] => int(0)["results"] => array(18) {
        [0] => array(5) {
            ["stats_link/_source"] => string(52)
            "/foxsoccer/bundesliga/teams/1-fc-nurnberg/stats/5131" ["team_name"] => string(14)
            "1. FC Nurnberg" ["stats_link/_title"] => string(28)
            "Stats - 1. FC Nurnberg Stats" ["stats_link/_text"] => string(5)
            "Stats" ["stats_link"] => string(76)
            "http://msn.foxsports.com/foxsoccer/bundesliga/teams/1-fc-nurnberg/stats/5131"
        }[1] => array(5) {
            ["stats_link/_source"] => string(54)
            "/foxsoccer/bundesliga/teams/1899-hoffenheim/stats/6859" ["team_name"] => string(15)
            "1899 Hoffenheim" ["stats_link/_title"] => string(29)
            "Stats - 1899 Hoffenheim Stats" ["stats_link/_text"] => string(5)
            "Stats" ["stats_link"] => string(78)
            "http://msn.foxsports.com/foxsoccer/bundesliga/teams/1899-hoffenheim/stats/6859"
```

and continues on for a however long.

I need to get the [team_name] and [stats_link] values out of that array. I've seen a number of examples on here, but the code I'm working with uses a function first and that's where I get confused. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you need `team_name` and `stats_link` removed or you want to use them someplace else ?

Comment: I want to save them to a variable if possible, not remove them.

Comment: I see the poor use of wording on my part. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get `team_name` and `stats_link` for other purposes you need to loop that array. Best way is to make another array with those values, eg:

```
$teams = array();
foreach($result['results'] as $team){
    $teams[$team['team_name']] = $team['stats_link'];
}
print_r($teams);

/*Array
(
    [1. FC Nurnberg] => http://msn.foxsports.com/foxsoccer/bundesliga/teams/1-fc-nurnberg/stats/5131
    [1899 Hoffenheim] => http://msn.foxsports.com/foxsoccer/bundesliga/teams/1899-hoffenheim/stats/6859
    .....*/
```

If you want those removed you can do:

```
foreach($result['results'] as $num => $team){
    unset($result['results'][$num]['team_name']);
    unset($result['results'][$num]['stats_link']);
}
print_r($result);

/*[0] => Array
                (
                    [stats_link/_source] => /foxsoccer/bundesliga/teams/1-fc-nurnberg/stats/5131
                    [stats_link/_title] => Stats - 1. FC Nurnberg Stats
                    [stats_link/_text] => Stats
                ) ...*/
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I used your first answer. If I can ask another question, how would I save those to variables? So in that for loop I could send them to a database or w.e. else I wanted.

Comment: `foreach($teams as $team => $link){ }`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($result['results'] as $a){
  unset($result['results'][$a]['stats_link']);
  unset($result['results'][$a]['team_name']);
}
```

it will remove 'stats_link' and 'team_name' of each key of the array.

Comment: Ok so I get the following error when I put that in on the unset lines: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting ',' or ')'`

Comment: No worries :) Now it's telling me `Warning: Illegal offset type` on those lines. Any thoughts?

Comment: Now it just repeats that error over and over. Before it just displayed it once. Thanks for all the help :/